# Fail to compile non-overloaded function in template argument

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, derived-class

I have these four classes :

```
class  BaseWrapper {
public:
  virtual void Process(int i) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Wrapper : public BaseWrapper {
public :
  Wrapper(T * arg): var(arg) {}
  void Process(int i) {
     this->var->Process(i);
  }
private:
  T * var;
};

class Base {
public :
  void Process(int) {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived() {
    BaseWrapper * wrap = new Wrapper<Derived>(this);
  }
  void       Process(std::string) {}
};
```

So basically the Derived class does not overload the Process method, and this method is required by the wrapper. When I compile this I get 'no matching function for call to Derived::Process(int)'.

Shouldn't the Process method still be defined in the Derived class?  I have also tried declaring the Process method in Base virtual, it didn't change anything.

I am not looking for a workaround (I have found one by overloading the Process method and calling the parent method in it) but I am trying to understand why this doesn't compile.

[EDIT]: If I remove the 'void Process(std::string)' from Derived, it compiles. Therefore, the problem seems to come from the presence of a different method with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change this:

```
void  Process(std::string) {}
```

to this:

```
void  Process(int) {}
```

your code will compile. This is a *strong* tip on why my code doesn't compile.

---

Let's see what's happening here:

We have:

```
Derived() {
  BaseWrapper * wrap = new Wrapper<Derived>(this);
}
```

which will call the constructor of `Wrapper` and will assign the data member `Wrapper` class has with the `Derived` class (the data member is a pointer, but that's not the big deal here).

Now, inside `Wrapper` class, we have:

```
void Process(int i) {
  this->var->Process(i);
}
```

which is the problem. You see, in the body of this function, we say take the data member of `Wrapper`, which points to class `Derived` and call `Process()` of the class we are pointing to! That's the `Derived` class, which has `void Process(std::string)`, thus we fairly receive this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
      this->var->Process(i);
```

which is similar to the error that you receive.

Hope this helps!
//+1 for a nice starter question for my day :)

---

If you do not want to overload the function, then help the compiler by saying that it should check the method inherited from the base class, rather than the one defined in `Derived` class, which should be the first choice for the compiler.

Then your code should like this:

```
class Base; // forward declaration, or just define Base class here

template<typename T>
class Wrapper : public BaseWrapper {
public :
  Wrapper(T * arg): var(arg) {}
  void Process(int i) {
     this->var->Base::Process(i); // Say that you want the Process() of Base
  }
private:
  T * var;
};
```

Comment: The thing is the Process(int) version of the method is already defined in the Base class, and I do not wish to overload it. but since it is defined in the base class shouldn't it be defined in the Derived class as well? this is the question I am asking myself. The Process(std::string) version is just another method that would not be used by the wrapper.